# How to change UIButton attributed text colour programatically?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I have a subclass (KeyButton) of UIButton where I am applying certain styles for the button. The following code adds the attributed text for buttons in the ViewController.

```
func superScriptText(text: String, button: KeyButton, fontSize: Int) {
    let font:UIFont? = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
    let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:CGFloat(fontSize))
    let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.font:font!])
    attString.setAttributes([.font:fontSuper!,.baselineOffset:15], range: NSRange(location:1,length:1))
    button.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)
}
```

How can I change the color of attributed text for the button in the class?

Answer (score 1):

Just change:

```
let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = 
     NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.font:font!])
```

to:

```
let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = 
     NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.font:font!, .foregroundColor: UIColor.red])
```

`NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor` is used for the text color, see more options in [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstringkey).

Comment: This will work if I put this directly in the ViewController, but how can I do it through UIButton subclass?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add the `.foregroundColor` key with a `UIColor` object as the value to the `NSAttributedString`s `attributes` dictionary.

Example (assuming you have added a custom button in storyboard):

```
class CustomButton: UIButton {
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        let text = "CustomButton"

        let font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: UIFont.buttonFontSize)
        let textColor = UIColor.orange

        let attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey: Any] = [
            .font: font,
            .foregroundColor: textColor
        ]

        let attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: attributes)
        self.setAttributedTitle(attributedText, for: .normal)
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work if I put this directly in the ViewController, but how can I do it through UIButton subclass?

Comment: I do not know **when** you want to set the title but I added an example to my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't do this through `UIButton` subclass. I created the subclass of `NSAttributtedText` and add the following method:

```
var textColor: UIColor?

func setSuperScript(text: String, button: KeyButton, fontSize: Int) {
    let font:UIFont? = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)
    let fontSuper:UIFont? = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size:CGFloat(fontSize))
    let attString:NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [.font:font!, .foregroundColor: textColor!])
    attString.setAttributes([.font:fontSuper!,.baselineOffset:15, .foregroundColor: textColor!,], range: NSRange(location:1,length:1))
    button.setAttributedTitle(attString, for: .normal)
}
```

I am setting the color based on the logic I have and then set the attributed string color accordingly.

Comment: @MilanNosáľ I was able to change the color of attributed string but my question is different. I have the subclass of my buttons and some of the buttons use attributed string. What you suggest is to change the attributed string color in ViewController which does not answer my question. I created the subclass of `NSAttributtedText` class, and changed the color there to apply for the buttons have attributed text, and then instantiated attribute string objects. I am voting +1 your answer. Thanks